# Subsetting a NumPy matrix using another matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have numpy matrices `X = np.matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])` and `y = np.matrix([1, 1, 0])` and I want to create two new matrices X_pos and X_neg based on y matrix. So hope my output will be the following: `X_pos == matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4]])` and `X_neg == matrix([[5, 6]])`. How can I do this?

Comment: Any particular reason why they are matrices?

Comment: It's easy for me to work with matrices in my previous and following code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to create a boolean mask out of `y`, this becomes simple.

```
mask = np.array(y).astype(bool).reshape(-1,)
X_pos = X[mask, :]
X_neg = X[~mask, :]

print(X_pos) 
matrix([[1, 2],
        [3, 4]])

print(X_neg)
matrix([[5, 6]])
```

Answer (score 1):

With [np.ma.masked_where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.masked_where.html)  routine:

```
x = np.matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
y = np.array([1, 1, 0])

m = np.ma.masked_where(y > 0, y)   # mask for the values greater than 0
x_pos = x[m.mask]                  # applying masking
x_neg = x[~m.mask]                 # negation of the initial mask

print(x_pos)
print(x_neg)
```